# ORA-00933: the SQL command does not end correctly

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem that has been bothering me for the past two days. I'm just starting on oracle;
I plan to display a result from the joining of several tables when the stock of products is greater than zero. But after entering my oracle query displays the error:ORA-00933: the SQL command does not end correctly.
I would like to have the help of the community as much as possible on this issue.

```
"SELECT 
    APSTOCK.CDOS AS CDOS , 
    APSTOCK.CODART AS CODART , 
    APSTOCK.CODMAG AS CODMAG , 
    APSTOCK.QTESTOCK AS QTESTOCK , 
    APMAG.LIBMAG AS LIBMAG , 
    APART.LIBART1 AS LIBART1 
    FROM  APSTOCK  LEFT  JOIN APART 
    ON APSTOCK.CODART  =  APART.CODART 
    LEFT  JOIN APMAG ON 
    APSTOCK.CODMAG =  APMAG.CODMAG 
    WHERE APSTOCK.CDOS = APART.CDOS 
    AND APSTOCK.CDOS = APMAG.CDOS
    AND APSTOCK.CODART LIKE 'B%'
    OR APSTOCK.CODART LIKE 'D%'
    IN
        (SELECT 
        APSTOCK.CDOS AS CDOS , 
        APSTOCK.CODART AS CODART , 
        APSTOCK.CODMAG AS CODMAG , 
        APSTOCK.QTESTOCK AS QTESTOCK , 
        APMAG.LIBMAG AS LIBMAG , 
        APART.LIBART1 AS LIBART1 
    FROM  APSTOCK  LEFT  JOIN APART 
    ON APSTOCK.CODART  =  APART.CODART 
    LEFT  JOIN APMAG ON 
    APSTOCK.CODMAG =  APMAG.CODMAG 
    WHERE APSTOCK.QTESTOCK>0)
    ORDER BY APSTOCK.CODART ASC";
```

Comment: Depending on the client you are running this in, the full error message you get may well point to the problematic are of the code. In SQL Developer etc. for instance it says "Error at Command Line : 16 Column : 5 ..." which points to the `IN` which is handing there on its own. (Incidentally, you are using outer joins, but your `where` clause is going to cause them to be treated as inner joins.)

Answer (score 1):

It is the `IN` that fails. What is *in* what?

---

Besides, using `OR` the way you used it might lead to unexpected results. Perhaps it should be enclosed into parenthesis, such as

```
and (apstock.codart like 'B%' or 
     apstock.codart like 'D%' 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your answers. I was able to rectify my code thanks to your instructions.

```
   SELECT 
    APSTOCK.CDOS AS CDOS , APSTOCK.CODART AS CODART , 
    APSTOCK.CODMAG AS CODMAG , APSTOCK.QTESTOCK AS QTESTOCK , 
    APMAG.LIBMAG AS LIBMAG , APART.LIBART1 AS LIBART1 
FROM  APSTOCK  LEFT  JOIN APART 
    ON APSTOCK.CODART  =  APART.CODART 
    LEFT  JOIN APMAG ON 
    APSTOCK.CODMAG =  APMAG.CODMAG 
    WHERE APSTOCK.CDOS = APART.CDOS 
    AND APSTOCK.CDOS = APMAG.CDOS
    AND (APSTOCK.CODART LIKE 'B%'
    OR APSTOCK.CODART LIKE 'D%')
    AND APSTOCK.QTESTOCK>0 
ORDER BY APSTOCK.CODART ASC;
```